# Unable to specify relative filepaths when program is launched with Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio, filepath

So the program compiles fine, and the executable is generated in $(SolutionDir)/Debug. When I run the executable from the debug folder itself, the program successfully scans the folder placed in the dubug directory for files. However, when I execute the program from Visual Studio, the program will fail unless i input the global path of that directory to the FindFirstFile function. Why?

For example: I have to do this in order to debug the program from Visual Studio:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define FILEPATH L"C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/$(SolutionDir)/Debug/Effects/*.dll"
#else
#define FILEPATH L"Effects/*.dll"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because when your application is running under the debugger, the working directory is not the *project's* directory, but rather the *debugger's* directory (or some other arbitrary directory that does not contain your DLL file).

Check (and fix) this by opening up your project's Properties and inspecting the Debugging settings. Specifically, Properties → Configuration Properties → Debugging. The "Working Directory" setting should be set to `$(TargetDir)`.

Comment: Nice catch. The value was set to $(ProjectDir)